# git - best way to checkout code from remote branch

Tags: git, version-control

my current workflow to deploy code is to branch a "releases" branch from master when i believe the code is in a stable state. on my production side, i do a simple `git fetch origin` and than check out my code via `git checkout origin/releases/v1.0` or whatever the release number is at that time. at this point my head is detached. so to avoid this, i just do something like `git checkout -b releases/v1.0 origin/releases/v1.0`. makes my `git status` look much better. to date, this has never been an issue (of course i do no modifications in this git repo).

i am essentially creating what i'll call leaf branches (correct term?. idk.) with my releases. i just found that `git checkout -t <branch>` will in fact do the checkout and creation of the local branch with the name i am looking for. however, it is setting up the upstream configuration that i don't need.

so based on my deployment process:

1. Does it really matter if i have a detached head if i just checkout from remote via `git checkout origin/releases/v1.0`?
2. Since my process does not lend itself to pushing any code from my production server, does it make sense to `git checkout -b releases/v1.0 origin/releases/v1.0` or have it actually tracked via `git checkout -t origin/releases/v1.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) It depends. Do you ever make changes to the releases branch when made? If so do you want to update your production whenever you do a fetch and checkout? If the answers are yes to the first and no to the second, you'll need to create a new branch. Otherwise, a dettached head is fine.

```
 git fetch
 git checkout origin/releases/v1.0
```

I'm not sure why you are running `git status`; that seems to be somewhat less useful if you are not making changes in production.

(2) I believe you need upstream configuration if you intend to pull down new changes to that branch. So this answer will depends on (1).

Comment: on my prod server, i only `fetch` releases. i never `pull` because i will never `merge/rebase` on my production server. so if i wanted to deploy new code, there must be a `releases` branch available with the new code. from there, i `checkout` the remote branch. regarding (2), no changes are made to my production releases on my prod server. so i will never make any changes to releases branch on my prod server that i will have to push to my central repo for others to pull down. with that said, i'll probably just do the `git checkout <remote-branch>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use git tags to accomplish this sort of deployment, if you are open to changing your workflow. Create a tag by:

```
git tag -a <tag_name>
```

then to checkout a specific tag:

```
git checkout tags/<tag_name>
```

More info about git tagging: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: i'll take a look into tags but i don't think its necessary for me based on how i deploy prod code via the releases branch.